# Passing props through root element data gets lost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ejs, react-props

I'm using React with EJS template. I'm just trying to pass data from api to react but i couldn't find a way to do it.
I have this api:

```
module.exports.home_get = async (req,res) => {
    try {
        await connectToDb()
        const events = await Event.find({})
        res.locals.events = events
        res.render("events.ejs")
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error)
    }
}
```

And my events.ejs file is this:

```
<%- include('./partials/_header.ejs') -%>
    <div id="myEvents" data-events="<%- JSON.stringify(events) -%>"></div>
<%- include('./partials/_footer.ejs') -%>
```

I'm trying to pass props from attributes like this:

```
const eventsNode = document.getElementById('myEvents');
        const eventsRoot = createRoot(eventsNode);
        eventsRoot.render(
          <StrictMode>
            <Events deneme={eventsNode.dataset}/>
          </StrictMode>
        );
```

And i got this deneme props on React side. But when i try to console.log it, it looks like this:

```
  deneme: DOMStringMap
    events: "[{"
```

I don't understand why my events props is missing. Only takes array and object brackets altough my real data is look like this:

```
[{"_id":"648122d837f0499d7ea6a0d3","title":"Sabah yürüyüşü","description":"Sabah yürüyüşünden sonra bara gidilecek.","location":"Ankara","date":"2023-06-17T03:40:00.000Z","organizer":"647c9257be2d7254600d75db","eventImage":"Uploads\\1686184664146.png","__v":0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solves the problem with changing from this code:

```
 <div id="myEvents" data-events="<%- JSON.stringify(events) -%>"></div>
```

to this code:

```
 <div id="myEvents" data-events="<%= JSON.stringify(events) %>"></div>
```

It looks like my problem is i was writing EJS syntax wrong.